# How to create intuition/steps to while creating a solver's config having various local search meta-heuristics using Optaplanner?

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am trying to solve a constraint optimization problem using optaplanner, for which I need to create a XML file which consists of solver(construction heuristics + local search) algorithms. I am confused which algo/ metaheuristic should I choose and how can I say that this particular metaheuristic combined with other eg( late acceptance followed by tabu search) will lead to better or worse results

Answer (score 2):

Fine-tuning the solver is an art on its own. Please find out more in [benchmarking and tweaking OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/benchmarking-and-tweaking/benchmarking-and-tweaking.html).